# Uso permitido de Python y librerías

Tags: python, licencias

Estoy terminando un proyecto en python, y tengo la duda de si es posible vender software que utilizan librerías como tkinter, plyer o infis.systray, se que python puede usarse comercialmente pero la licencia de cada librería influye en esto?

Comment: Duda: ¿ya revisaste los términos y condiciones de cada una de esas bibliotecas?

Comment: Deberias leer el termino de las librerias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Ten en cuenta que no somos abogados.. asi que no podriamos darte informacion legal al respecto

Comment: Si, pero no especifican bien el uso comercial, por ejemplo la licencia “creative commons” de tkinter

Comment: Obviamente las licencias de cada librería importan, no obstante infis.systray es BSD, plyer solo pide que se agregue una nota de renuncia de garantía, puedes usarlo comercialmente sin problemas. tkinter que yo sepa no es creative commons, se licencia bajo PSF LICENSE 2.2 (la licencia de Python) y tcl/tk es de estilo BSD: http://www.tcl.tk/software/tcltk/license.html.

Comment: Por cierto, no se debe confundir comercial con propietario, muchas licencias permiten el uso comercial (animo de lucro) pero no permiten hacer que tu código sea propietario (la copia, redistribución o modificación están, en alguna medida, prohibidos por su propietario), GPL sin ir más lejos, puedes venderlo pero el usuario tiene que tener a su disposición el código fuente.... Debes tener esto en cuenta, también. Lo mejor es que te leas detenidamente cada licencia, es un tema complejo. Por cierto, descargo de responsabilidad, no soy jurista.... XD

Comment: si la verdad es todo un tema, deberian ser un poco más claros o tendria que ser más fácil entender cada licencia para no tener que hacer una carrera para poder entenderlas jajaj y con respecto al uso personal sin distribuir ni comercializar debe estar permitido por todas esas librerias no? Yo imagino que si son accesibles en descarga deben poder usarse para armar un programa de uso personal